Recombine data with multiple different delimiters
There is an array of data:
https://example.com:description of the site/application:category
http://example.com:description of the site/application:category
android://package name:description of the site/application:category
android://package name|description of the site/application|category

I want to split the data into 3 columns:



URL
Description
Category




https://example.com
description of the site/application
category


http://example.com
description of the site/application
category


android://package name
description of the site/application
category


android://package name
description of the site/application
category



As I understand it, it is necessary to add a regEx to ignore the first ":" and also 2 argument for the divisor "|"
I tried this expression, but the output is incorrect
cat * | awk -F["|"][:] '{print $1,$2, $3}'


where can : and | appear when not acting as separators? just in the url?

And if there is a url, is it always at the beginning of the string?

Please [edit] to provide input and expected output as pure text (put \```none on a line above the example text, and \```  below it). See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Your desired output has four items, wheras you say it should be three columns.

Can description of the site/application or category contain :s or |s? Can the URL contain additional :s or |s? Please use truly representative values in examples, not just the same general strings repeated on every line, so we can best help you.

Using any awk:
$ awk -F'[:|]' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/:/,RS); sub(RS,":",$1)} 1' file
https://example.com     description of the site/application     category
http://example.com      description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category

or, if the OFS character can't be present in the URL in the input:
$ awk -F'[:|]' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1; sub(OFS,":")} 1' file
https://example.com     description of the site/application     category
http://example.com      description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category

Set OFS to something other than \t as you see fit.
Please read the POSIX spec to learn what bracket expression such as the ones you used, ["|"][:], and the one I used, [:|], mean.
Having said that, I suspect the OPs real input probably looks something like this (where additional :s or |s can appear in the URL and/or description, but no literal blanks can be in the URL):
$ cat file
https://example.com:description of : the site/application:category
http://example.com:description: of the site/application:category
android://package%20name:description of the site/application:category
android://package%20name|description of the site/application|category
android://package_name:17:something:description of the :huge: site/application:category

and then you can get the output you want using the following sed script (using a sed that has -E to enable EREs, e.g. GNU and BSD seds):
$ sed -E 's/([^ ]+)[:|]([^ ].*)[:|]/\1\t\2\t/' file
https://example.com     description of : the site/application   category
http://example.com      description: of the site/application    category
android://package%20name        description of the site/application     category
android://package%20name        description of the site/application     category
android://package_name:17:something     description of the :huge: site/application      category

or using any sed:
$ sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[:|]\([^ ].*\)[:|]/\1\t\2\t/' file
https://example.com     description of : the site/application   category
http://example.com      description: of the site/application    category
android://package%20name        description of the site/application     category
android://package%20name        description of the site/application     category
android://package_name:17:something     description of the :huge: site/application      category

Those sed commands assume a description contains at least 1 blank and doesn't start with a : or word:word - if that's not the case then there is no way to separate a description from a URL given what we know so far about the input.

-E has made it into the standard!

@jhnc so it has, good! I see nextfile made it in for awk now too. I had a bunch of tickets with the POSIX folks that got accepted and so I'd hoped would make it in too (e.g. defining the value of $0 in an END section, defining what NF++ does, defining what splitting on a null FS does, etc.), but looks like I opened them too late. Ah well, next time...

If format can be one of:
url:description:category

url|description|category

and only url can contain extra : or |, then to change to tab separators with sed:
sed -E 's/(.*)([:|])(.*)\2(.*)/\1\t\3\t\4/' file

or slightly more efficiently:
sed -E 's/(.*)([:|])(.*)\2/\1\t\3\t/' file

The first .* consumes as much as possible, so also consumes any surplus : and |
Change \t if tabs are not the desired new separators.

You may notice that you have 4 fields per line when splitting with [:|]:
awk -F '[:|]' '{ print NF }' infile

Output:
4
4
4
4

So, assuming all your lines are formatted in this way, you can get 3 columns by joining fields 1 and 2, e.g.:
awk -F '[:|]' -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1":"$2, $3, $4 }' infile

Output:
https://example.com     description of the site/application     category
http://example.com      description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category
android://package name  description of the site/application     category


you might also need to account for http://host:port/path or http://host/path1:path2

@jhnc: Not according the OP's examples

true, but the answer should help anyone

Maybe also note that you can avoid the useless use of cat with awk '...' *

@jhnc maybe the description and/or category could contain :s and then any solution that tries to accommodate multiple :s in the URL would be wrong.

@EdMorton if they can appear anywhere, then surely the line is unparsable without extra rules?

@jhnc. Yes, that's correct. Until the OP provides more truly representative sample input/output we're all just guessing at what they might really have in their input. I strongly suspect the URL doesn't really have blanks in it and the real solution will end up being something that uses non-blanks up til the last : before the first "word" of the description as the URL, the last : to the end of the line as the "category" and the string in between as the "description" but we'll see what the OP ends up telling us and showing in an example.

@EdMorton perhaps amusingly, on linux, : can appear in the command interpreter field of /etc/passwd

@jhnc I just updated my answer to show what I think the OPs input will really look like and a sed script to work on it.
